# Include JSP page ignores custom headers

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet that includes a JSP page along with custom header:

```
    rsp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    rsp.setContentType("text/html");
    rsp.addHeader("X-MyHeader", "Test");
    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("MyPage.jsp");
    if ( rd != null )
        rd.include( req, rsp );
```

The problem is, the custom header is not included in the output stream.

I understand that an included service cannot add or change headers, that such changes are ignored, but in this case it's not an included service that's attempting to add a header, it's the service doing the include, and it's a .jsp page that's being included not a service.

How can I include a custom header in the outer service (there's actually only one service here) while also including a .jsp page?

Comment: This is completely legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues at play. The response header did not appear in the output stream because the service was already included via a `<jsp:include page=service...>` action element, *and* because the output stream writer was obtained before setting the header.

The complete original JSP page consists of only 3 lines:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:include page="/myservice"/>
```

As you can see, that page includes the service, which subsequently executes:

```
PrintWriter w = rsp.getWriter();
...
rsp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
rsp.setContentType("text/html");
rsp.addHeader("X-MyHeader", "Test");
RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("MyPage.jsp");
if ( rd != null )
    rd.include( req, rsp );
```

Not only are there nested pages, but once the output stream writer is obtained, the Headers cannot be updated. Either condition would cause the problem.

See [Why can't HttpServletResponse Headers be updated AFTER getWriter() is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508445/why-cant-httpservletresponse-headers-be-updated-after-getwriter-is-called) for more information.

The solution that worked for me was to include the header from the original JSP page (bypassing both problems):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<% response.setHeader("X-MyHeader", "Test"); %>
<jsp:include page="/myservice"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You see, JSP pages get coded and compiled as Servlets. So a JSP page is basically a Servlet in disguise, so by invoking it you actually redirect to a different Servlet. If you want to change the headers within the JSP you can do it like this:

```
<%
response.setHeader("X-MyHeader", "Test");
%>
```

I you only want to include some markup in your original Servlet I suggest you store in a text file and then append the content of the file to the Servlet's outpustream.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. Since the JSP page is basically a servlet in disguise, I would not expect it to work; it is documented that an included servlet cannot add or change headers. But, in my original code, it is not the included servlet adding the header, it is the including servlet; and in that case the documentation clearly says that the caller's response is left intact. So where is my custom header?

Comment: Then invoke your JSP with request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp).forward(request, response);

Comment: No joy. That did not work, either. The custom header steadfastly refuses to appear. If I don't include/forward a page with RequestDispatcher then the custom header appears. As soon as I invoke a RequestDispatcher method the header goes missing.

Comment: It turns out that there is an index.jsp that includes data from a service that subsequently includes a jsp page. This explains why the service itself could not set the headers because it was the target of an include. Further, I had placed the <% response.setHeader() %> in the innermost jsp, rather than the index.jsp. Of course, properly placed, it works fine.

Comment: Great! It is always important to be aware of the flow of your application.

Comment: Indeed. It's been years since I put in the index.jsp and just forgot about it. Once I was forced to follow the full flow path it became obvious. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Though the conversation in this answer was apparently fruitful--it lead the poster to find a solution--, this response is just misleading: there was nothing wrong with the code posted in OP. It'd be better if @Kikin-Sama or if Scott posted the real answer, namely, check if the servlet hasn't been already included. I'm downvoting it to avoid confusion. I'd upvote after appropriate edit / repost.