# How do I return status code 500 in the Response from Java Adapter?

Tags: java, http, servlets, ibm-mobilefirst, httpresponse

The service returns some error status 500, and I would like to return it to the client.
Actually, it was returned and I can see that (status, error message ...) in client side (webApp) in the HTTP response object,
but the third time the mobile-first server (where the JAVA Http adapter is running) must be restated.
by success response (status 200) not need to restart or to do anything, the server is running stable and fine.

Here is my code:

```
    public void execute(HttpUriRequest req, HttpServletResponse resultResponse)
        throws IOException, IllegalStateException, SAXException {

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(req);

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        resultResponse.sendError(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        //was tried but the same result
        //resultResponse.setStatus(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        //resultResponse.getWriter().close();
    }else{
        response.getEntity().writeTo(resultResponse.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```

Maybe this combination does not work together or something went wrong with my resultResponse!

Comment: Maybe have a look at the error and please [edit] that into your question? Receiving a 500 error is almost always an exception that popped up somewhere

Comment: that's not an error from my side; as a client, I don't care, I have to forward everything I received from the web services operations/endpoint

Comment: What does the server logs tell you when you have received Status code 500 from the backend?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508910/10196399) and in Servlet book - Section SRV.5.2 Headers of the Java™ Servlet Specification Version 2.4, the right way is:

```
ServletOutputStream os = resultResponse.getOutputStream();
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    response.getEntity().writeTo(resultResponse.getOutputStream());

} else {
    resultResponse.sendError(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(),
        response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    response.getEntity().getContent().close();

    os.write(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase().getBytes());
}
os.flush();
os.close();
```